# VB.net String Extraction

Tags: vb.net, string

At the company I work at, I have a software that I am developing in vb.net. This software uses a web browser control to load an excel file that the employee can modify. If then saves a copy of the excel file as an excel file for future modification, it saves it as a pdf file, to send to the customer, then prints the first page twice. I am trying to create a quote list. Quote File names are structured as follows...

```
12345 My Company Name Here 10-25-2013.pdf
```

Is there any way to "extract" just the "My Company Name Here" in the above example. I tried removing all numbers, and then the - and .pdf from the string, but it actually makes it where fewer results appear in the list view control. Any Ideas?

```
Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo("Z:\Quotes\" & Today.Year & "\" & Today.Month _
        & " " & MonthName(Today.Month))
    Dim diar1 As IO.FileInfo() = di.GetFiles("*.pdf")
    Dim dra As IO.FileInfo
    ListView1.View = View.Details
    ListView1.Columns.Clear()
    ListView1.Columns.Add("Quote Number")
    ListView1.Columns.Add("Customer Name")
    ListView1.Columns(0).Width = -2
    ListView1.Columns(1).Width = -2

    For Each dra In diar1
        If dra.ToString.Contains("Product") = False Or dra.ToString.Contains("Thumbs.db") Then
            Dim newIrm() = dra.ToString.Split(" ")
            Dim NumericCharacters As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("\d")
            Dim nonNumericOnlyString As String = NumericCharacters.Replace(newIrm(2), String.Empty)
            ListView1.Items.Add(New ListViewItem({newIrm(0), newIrm(1) & newIrm(2)}))
        End If
    Next
```

Filename Format:

```
 Z:\Quotes\2013\10 October\12345-RR My Company Name Here 10-25-2013.pdf
```

Comment: Do you have control over the file name?

Comment: How is that full string being generated?

Comment: Is the length of the prefix numbers constant?  The length of the postfix string looks constant (14).

Comment: @Karl Anderson I do, but to do so would be to change the format that has existed for the last 6 years, which would be over 300,000 quotes.

Comment: @nhgrif, no the length is not constant...for quote revisions, a -R is appended to the end of the string. An R is appended for each revision.

Comment: Complete File name is above:

Comment: But the postfix part is a constant length if the date uses leading zeros (does it?).  And the prefix part is variable length, but the first space is the first char before the company name in every case, right?

Comment: Pull the file name off the full path, then split the resulting string into an array using the space character. You then iterate through the array starting at the second element, and append all the rest onto a string, adding a space back in (since you split on it). Do not add the last element of the array. Problem solved.

Comment: @helrich that does not work since the "My Company Name Here" is a variable length Company Name containing one or more spaces.

Comment: @nhgrif I will be using that suggestion, thank you. I didn't even think about that. You can put that as the answer if you want

Comment: If you are assembling the file name, can't you grab the parts you want then?

Comment: It absolutely does work. The resulting array would be `{"12345-RR, "My, "Company", "Name", Here", "10-25-2013.pdf"}`. You want all elements except the first and last.

Comment: Is the Company name always a space before and after?

Comment: @helrich is right too.  You can split it into an array and grab every index that's not 0 or array.length

Comment: Aha, that answered my final question. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By assuming that the company name is always surrounded by blank spaces and that all the surrounding text does not contain any, you can use `IndexOf` and `LastIndexOf`. Sample code:

```
Dim input As String = "Z:\Quotes\2013\10 October\12345-RR My Company Name Here 10-25-2013.pdf"
Dim companyName As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(input)

companyName = companyName.Substring(companyName.IndexOf(" "), companyName.LastIndexOf(" ") - companyName.IndexOf(" ")).Trim()
```

If these conditions do not fully apply, you would have to describe clearly the constraints in order to update this code. Without systematically-applied constraints, there wouldn't be any way to deliver an accurate solution for this problem.

Comment: Your Code is just returning the letter: "M", is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: @JustinE I guess that using wrong inputs. If you copy these three lines, it would return "My Company Name Here". Please, tell me your exact inputs.

Comment: @JustinE OK. But, please, don't use it blindly and understand what it does exactly: the first line, removes all the directories and the .pdf part; and the second line finds the substring starting in the first " " and ending in the last " ".

Comment: Great, I don't know a ton about arrays and the works, but I do know a bit. This definitely helps, and I appreciate the explanation as well.

Answer (score 1):

The postfix (date.pdf) is a constant size assuming your date format uses leading zeros.
The prefix is a variable size, however the first space of the complete file name always comes before the first character of the company name.

Using these two facts, you can easily find the index of the first and last character of the company "extract" the company name using this information.

Alternatively, you can split the file name into an array using space as your delimiter.  You can then grab every index of the array, excluding the first and last index, and combine these elements seperated by a space.